# How to rearrange data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to rearrange the data that I have to be displayed differently.

From the 4 rows, I have to the 18 rows below as per the image. Please help.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
={"Team name","Player name","Country","Gender"; 
 QUERY({B2:B, G2:I; B2:B, J2:L; B2:B, M2:O; B2:B, P2:R; B2:B, S2:U}, 
 "where Col2 is not null order by Col1", 0)}
```

Comment: Thank you but I managed to get it done by using Sort feature.